# Flutter map get address

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary

This is all my code. I want it to be able to search for places from lat , lng , and if lat,lng is not there, it will search for places from names. But now it's like when searching for a place from the name. In the part where the name is converted to lat,lng it's correct but my marker appears in the middle of the sea

```
 LatLng centerMap = LatLng(13.730452094709594, 100.64180575311175);

 @override
 void initState() {
 findLocation();
 super.initState();
 }

 void findLocation() async {
var lat = double.tryParse(searchitems[0].address![widget.index].latitude.toString());
var lng = double.tryParse(searchitems[0].address![widget.index].longitude.toString());
if (lat != null && lng != null) {
  centerMap = LatLng(lat, lng);
} else {
  var name = searchitems[0].name;
  var addr = '${searchitems[0].address![widget.index].addr1!}, ${searchitems[0].address![widget.index].thanon!}, ${searchitems[0].address![widget.index].tambon!}, ${searchitems[0].address![widget.index].province!}';
  var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(addr);
  var first = addresses.first;
  centerMap = LatLng(first.coordinates.latitude!, first.coordinates.longitude!);
  print("Location not found, searching for name: $name and address: $addr");
}
print("map:$centerMap");
}


GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: centerMap,
              zoom: 16.0,
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a controller in Google maps, then when you call the API and get new `lat long`, you can animate camera to that position like this:

```js
 Future<void> _goToNewPosition() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_kLake));
  }
```

There's also an example on the official package, you can check it out by this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)

Comment: When I build it gives Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method findAddressesFromQuery on channel github.com/aloisdeniel/geocoder)